# Improve execution time of select distinct query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

[image]I'm having issues getting a full result set back for the query below. When i select distinct top 10000 i get results in seconds. When i take this out it keeps running for over 1 hour. I checked and tried to index the fields such as company reg num + country inc but makes no difference. Toad suggested adding the following index:

```
USE [BW_DCF];
    GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Nonclustered_WeccoParty_OverallStatus]
ON [CORE].[WeccoParty]
([OverallStatus])
INCLUDE (
[GtId], [CrmPartyId], [FirstName], [LastName], [LegalName], [CountryInc], 
[BusinessClass], [RmFullName], [PbeFullName], [OverallClientStatus], 
[OverallRpStatus], [CompanyRegNum] 
)
WITH
(
PAD_INDEX = OFF,
FILLFACTOR = 100,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON,
DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE
)
ON [BW_DCF_Group1];
GO



   select distinct wp1.GtId, 
  wp1.CrmPartyId, 
  wp1.LegalName, 
  wp1.BusinessClass, 
  wp1.RmFullName, 
  wp1.PbeFullName, 
  wp1.OverallClientStatus, 
  wp1.OverallRpStatus, 
  wp1.FirstName,
  wp1.LastName,  
  wp1.LegalName,
  wp1.CountryInc,
  wp1.CompanyRegNum,
  wp2.GtId, 
  wp2.CrmPartyId, 
  wp2.LegalName, 
  wp2.BusinessClass, 
  wp2.RmFullName, 
  wp2.PbeFullName, 
  wp2.OverallClientStatus, 
  wp2.OverallRpStatus,  
  wp2.FirstName,
  wp2.LastName,
  wp2.LegalName,
  wp2.CountryInc,
  wp2.CompanyRegNum
     from CORE.WeccoParty wp1
      join CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum
                    and wp1.CountryInc = wp2.CountryInc     
                    and wp1.GtId <> wp2.GtId 
                and wp1.OverallStatus = 'Onboarded'
            and wp2.OverallStatus = 'Onboarded'
```

Comment: Could you add execution plan?

Comment: yes, i've added now

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `wp1.GtId <> wp2.GtId` is the offender. Can you post the DDL and any indexes you have on your table? For the plan, use [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), images aren't helpful.

Comment: Looking at that image though, all of those are Clustered Index **Scans** (not seeks). I have no idea how many rows are in your table, but I suspect quite a few. As a result, SQL Server is having the check the value of **every** row, it's not using the Index to make things easier. Good indexing is probably going to help here.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Long query times often lie on overflowing RAM space or a database which has insufficient RAM space given. This query is completely normal and there is not really any performance boost possible.

As a solution I would give the database more ram to work with.

In my experience I saw that sql-server has huge issues when it lacks on RAM space. PostgreSQL seems to deal with it a lot quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) Appreciated.

Comment: @Shuumi how did you come to the conclusion that RAM was the issue by the way? The OP hasn't mentioned the amount of RAM that have at all. I no doubt suspect that a PostgreSQL server could well run poorly as well with a small amount of RAM. A poorly designed database, or a poorly written query, for example, will run badly regardless of the resources or environment it's running in (I'm not saying that the OP's query is poorly written, or the database is poorly designed. I don't have enough information to state that).

Comment: @Larnu that is just my experience. His query looks simple and a runtime of over an hour is rare even on a complicated query. The thing with Postgre is actually tested by me. I built two similar databases and gave them too low amount of RAM. PostgreSQL was quicker to execute. I understand that this was a rash answer and not enough information was given to conclude what I said, but I just threw a fact from my own experience. The fact that it worked is just a happy accident of an educated guess.

Comment: By optimizing the query you will reduce memory and runtime cost - so this should be done first.

Comment: @PowerStat indeed. The OP's query plan shows everything is a Scan, not a Seek, so no amount of RAM is going to make the problem go away.

Comment: There is nothing simple about a query which uses `SELECT DISTINCT` on 20 columns from both tables on a self-join.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for adding the execution plan. I can give you only some tips.

1. Predicate OverallStatus = 'Onboarded' is the one which selects data for comparison. How many rows does it select from the total rows in CORE.WeccoParty? If it's less than <5-10% you can try to create an index on it. You can also first create a temporary table with the data filtered by this predicate and then join them.
2. If more data is required to be selected from CORE.WeccoParty than 5-10% it will be better to perform a full scan on this table to eliminate selection of the data by using two indexes and then joining results by the hash operation.
3. Looks like join between data selected by wp1 and wp2 is performed by the merge operation. This operation requires first sorting of the input data for wp1 and wp2 try to eliminate it by adding hint for hash join:

> FROM CORE.WeccoParty wp1   **INNER HASH JOIN** CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on
>   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum

or nested loop join:

> FROM CORE.WeccoParty wp1   **INNER LOOP JOIN** CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on
>   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum

4. You can also try to create a supporting index and test the performance

> CREATE INDEX IX_WeccoParty_1
>   ON CORE.WeccoParty(OverallStatus,CompanyRegNum,CountryInc,GtId)

5. Did you try to update statistics on CORE.WeccoParty table.

By looking at the execution plan I bet that this merge join could be the culprit plus extraction of the data before joining data.